# On DropDown/HTML Select Show Modal PopUp

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following code/fiddle that when the button is clicked a dropdown is shown & when a user chooses from one of the options Bootstrap's modal window appears.  As of now the code consists of html tags... button, ul and li.  Though it needs to be within html tags select & option, so the iPhone's built in scroll is triggered/appears.

Any suggestions on how the code in the fiddle can be adjusted for this?

CSS

```
button {
  border: 1px solid #34740e;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 8px 68px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

button.dropdown-toggle {
  float: none;
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button.small {
  padding: 10px 48px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">FIND: Restaurant Nearby<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#consumergoods" data-toggle="modal">AppleBees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#consumergoods2" data-toggle="modal">McDonalds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#consumergoods3" data-toggle="modal">Wendys</a></li>
    <li><a href="#consumergoods4" data-toggle="modal">Taco Bell</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="consumergoods" data-target="#consumergoods">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header orange">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong></strong>AppleBees</h4>
        <p>Description Here: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="consumergoods2" data-target="#consumergoods2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header orange">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong></strong>McDonalds</h4>
        <p>Description Here: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="consumergoods3" data-target="#consumergoods3">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header orange">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong></strong>Wendys</h4>
        <p>Description Here: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="consumergoods4" data-target="#consumergoods4">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header orange">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong></strong>Taco Bell</h4>
        <p>Description Here: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://goo.gl/WFnSrX)

Comment: Feel free to grab the code from the fiddle and entered into SO's module.  I tried a few times.

Comment: Are you ok with a JavaScript-based solution? A bit of testing suggests that the non-JS approach of adding `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes to `option` tags within a `select` element works fine in, say, Firefox and IE, but not in Webkit (Chrome/iPhone Safari). I think it could be resolved with additional JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to show on a mobile device a list of 300 restaurants and info about each all on one page that doesn't scroll down too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using JQuery and ofcourse making some changes to your markup:

**HTML** (remove the dropdown and use a bootstrap select box)

```
<select id="selectbox">
  <option value="#consumergoods">AppleBees</option>
  <option value="#consumergoods2">McDonalds</option>
  <option value="#consumergoods3">Wendys</option>
  <option value="#consumergoods4">Taco Bell</option>
</select>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<!-- Modal 2 -->
<!-- Modal 3 -->
<!-- Modal 4 -->
```

Note: You need to add the attribute `value` to the options and assign the modal id's to it. Also give an id to the `select` so we can target it using JQuery.

Now for the fun part - **JQuery**

```
$("#selectbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "#consumergoods") {
        $('#consumergoods').modal('show');
      }
    if ($(this).val() == "#consumergoods2") {
        $('#consumergoods2').modal('show');
      }
    if ($(this).val() == "#consumergoods3") {
        $('#consumergoods3').modal('show');
      }
    if ($(this).val() == "#consumergoods4") {
        $('#consumergoods4').modal('show');
      }
 });
```

As you can see, on change of the options the corresponding `value` is read and the appropriate modal can be shown.

[Updated your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5p54erh/2/)

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you!  Weird, though I can not get it to run locally ... as of in the last 45 minutes; will keep trying!

Comment: Figured out why the modal window wasn't appearing/popping up... you have to put your JS script at the bottom before the closing body tag.  Thanks again!